# AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Mocks not yet satisfied: on using chaining with nock while testing Redux actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, mocha.js, enzyme, nock

I am trying to test an action in a React project with redux.

The test i am trying to do using Mocha,Enzyme is for a DELETE_USER action which is dispatched first on pressing a delete button and onSuccess of the action another action LOAD_ALL_USERS is dispatched which performs a get request.
Following is the code for test i tried , which gives the error as in the topic:

```
it('should call the /users endpoint with a user ID', (done) => {
        const deleteUserResponse = {userId: 1337};
        const mapActions = (actions) => ({
            deleteActions: filterForAction(actions, 'DELETE_USER'),
            loadAllUserActions: filterForAction(
                actions,
                'LOAD_ALL_USERS'
            )
        });
        const loadAllUsersResponse =
            [
                {
                    id: 1337,
                    email: 'testuser9@some-company.com',
                    firstName: 'John',
                    lastName: 'Doe',                   
                    active: false
                },
                {
                    id: 1338,
                    email: 'adamsmith@mail.com',
                    firstName: 'Adam',
                    lastName: 'Smith',                   
                    active: true
                }
            ];
        const sampleApiSearchParams = {
            locale: 'en-GB',
            pageSize: 10,
            sortBy: 'userId',
            sortDirection: 'desc',
            location: 'Zurich'
        };
        const sampleReactTableSearchParams = {
            filtered: [
                {id: 'userId', value: '1id'},
                {id: 'userFirstName', value: 'fname'},
                {id: 'userLastName', value: 'lname'},
                {id: 'userEmail', value: 'maill'}
            ],
            sorted: [{id: 'userId', desc: true}],
            pageSize: 10
        };
        const scope = nock('http://localhost')
            .delete('users/1337')
            .reply(200, deleteUserResponse)
            .get(uri=>uri.includes('users'),{...sampleApiSearchParams})
            .reply(200, loadAllUsersResponse);
        const store = mockStore(
            {
               stringResources: {
                                'deleteuser.confirm.title': 'User Delete Confirm',
                                'deleteuser.confirm.description':
                                    'Are you sure you want to delete the user?',
                                'deleteuser.notification.message.success':
                                    'is successfully deleted.'
                            
                },
                userManagement: {
                    table: {
                        searchParams: sampleReactTableSearchParams
                    }
                }
            });
        const actual = actions.deleteUser(1337)
        store.dispatch(actual);
        setTimeout(() => {
            scope.done();
            const {deleteActions, loadAllUsersActions} = mapActions(store.getActions());
            
            expect(
                deleteActions[1].meta['redux-pack/LIFECYCLE']
            ).toBe('success');
            expect(deleteActions[1].payload).toEqual(
                deleteUserResponse
            );
            
            //expect(loadAllUsersActions[1].payload).toEqual(loadAllUsersResponse);
            done();
        }, 50);
    });
});
```

If i comment the 'scope.done()' the test passes, but http.get request is not getting called so the 'loadAllUsersActions' is undefined. How can i solve this , what is that i am doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like your `.get(uri=>uri.includes('users'),{...sampleApiSearchParams})` isn't actually matching the GET request being made. Try running your test with DEBUG enabled for Nock. https://github.com/nock/nock#debugging It will give you details on what is not lining up.

Comment: The 'Debug' really helped , thank you.